# Is there a way to hide this message from the console window in Visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

[image: console window]

I just want it to print my output, then once complete say just the "press any key to close this window" part.

I checked the settings menu that's suggested in the console, but there's only an option to fully close the program once compiled.

I've been on Google for weeks and can't seem to find an answer!

Answer (score 1):

Run your program from a regular shell/console, rather than your IDE. Then you won't see the IDE's helpful messages.

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty easy to do.  Use **(start without debugging)** from the debugging menu, and you will get the message you are after.   If you **(start with debugging)** the program will finish and close the window which is the behavior you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Tool-> Options -> Debugging -> General -> Automatically close the console when debugging stops

Comment: You are just repeating the message/suggestion shown in the console window in the question.